# Jquery - Draggable breaks after image Swap

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im using Jquery and JqueryUI to:

- I have `<img>` that contains an image
- There is an edit button on this image that allows it to be repositioned (wrapping div overflow:hidden) and then the user can click cancel or save to send an AJAX call with the final position, "saving the relative crop of the image" (think like facebook profile picture thumb selector works)
- A user also has an option list of ~8 images (similar to twitter changing ones background from samples) that he/she can pick from. On click the image in the `<img>` tag is swapped with the one the user clicked on and the position reset to top:0px, leftpx;

This all works well and good.

BUT If an image has ALREADY been dragged around - then a different image after the swap can not be dragged around. In inspect element - the code updates with the correct top and left coordinates and it adds the right classes - but the image does not move.

If code would be helpful - I can provide that.

EDIT** Code Below

id=image_slice_wrapper has overflow hidden with fixed dimensions.
 has src on page load with left & top from DB (saved)

```
<div id="image_slice_wrapper">
<img id="draggable" class="slice_img ui-draggable" style="position:relative; left:-1000px; top:-250px" src="images/ducati.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Edit Button Script to make Div Draggable (Extra styling stuff removed)

```
$("#edit_button").click(function() {
$( ".slice_img" ).draggable({ disabled: false, drag: function(){                        
$(".slice_img").css("cursor","move");   
});
```

Save button to Lock div back up (AJAX & styling removed)

```
$("#save_button").click(function() {
$('.slice_img').draggable( "option", "disabled", true );
});
```

Img replace script (slice_thumb is the image preview to trigger swap)

```
$(".slice_thumb").click(function() {
var new_image = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
$(".slice_img").attr("src",new_image);   
$(".slice_img").attr("style","left:0px; top:0px;");
});
```

So again: If I drag an image around. And then replace that image with another image. The new image is not VISIBLY draggable. However I can still see the top and left styles being changed,  and the right classes being added to the element.

Comment: Code is always helpful.. jsfiddle.net is even better. First thought though, are you binding to the events using live?

Comment: @Todd not sure what "using live" means. Can you clarify?

Comment: Look at the jQuery docs for the "live" method (http://api.jquery.com/live/). It's used for automatically rebinding events to dynamically generated objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem. Still not obvious why this works.

I changed the image replace script with:

```
$(".slice_thumb").click(function() {
    var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    $(".slice_img").attr("style","left:0px; top:0px;");
    $("#draggable").after('<img src=" " />').attr("src", src).addClass("slice_img ui-draggable").attr("style","position:relative; left:0px; top:0px").attr("id","draggable");
});
```

It actually replaces the img src (like it was doing before) but also creates a blank image after `<img src="_">`. And for some reason jquery likes this. The new image is draggable in the code (I can see the position changing) - and visibly draggable in the DOM. Cool!